# Airflow DAG is getting stuck in running state indefinitely - No viable dags retrieved

Tags: airflow

I created a dag following the same format with already existing dags (which run just fine without any issues for as long as I know) and once I deploy to production, without even activating the dag, it starts running. And it is stuck in an infinite state. What I get from the scheduler is below

```
[2023-05-22 08:59:20,191] {scheduler_job.py:182} INFO - Started process (PID=567061) to work on /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/git-repo/dags/rebates_to_mysql/scripts/tst_script.py
[2023-05-22 08:59:20,192] {scheduler_job.py:633} INFO - Processing file /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/git-repo/dags/rebates_to_mysql/scripts/tst_script.py for tasks to queue
[2023-05-22 08:59:20,193] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - [2023-05-22 08:59:20,193] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/git-repo/dags/rebates_to_mysql/scripts/tst_script.py
[2023-05-22 08:59:23,256] {scheduler_job.py:645} WARNING - No viable dags retrieved from /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/git-repo/dags/rebates_to_mysql/scripts/tst_script.py
[2023-05-22 08:59:23,262] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/git-repo/dags/rebates_to_mysql/scripts/tst_script.py took 3.074 seconds
```

airflow version:2.1.0

I tried to create the dag in a different directory and write just a very simple python script that sends an email. And after deploying, I was keep getting this email over and over again. I did not even activate the dag and it kept sending emails.

Comment: Can u please share your code?